# Trajectory Similarity Measurement with Shapely or other Python libraries

Tags: python, shapely

Are any of the famous trajectory similarity measurement methods such as Dynamic Time Warping(DTW), Edit Distance based methods or Longest Common Subsequence based Measures implemented in shapely or any other python based libraries?

My end goal is to find similar sections between two trajectories. I do not care about the time stamps and when the trajectories are traversed. The lengths may be different. A short part of one trajectory may overlap with another trajectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dynamic Time Warping, it seems that the feature is in development on Scipy https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7638, keep an eye on it and in the meantime you can try using the implementation from [this Github repository](https://github.com/shunsukeaihara/pydtw) which is released as a Python package called `pydtw`.

For the Edit Distance there is a small Python package called `editdistance` (https://pypi.org/project/editdistance/) that seems to come from [this Github repository](https://github.com/aflc/editdistance).